# Responsive Website Header for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, web, responsive

I need the header on the website I'm working on the be responsive. Right now the image will be cropped when resizing. I would like it to maintain the same ratios no matter the size.

The website is: hoganfrick.com

A website that has a header similar to this is: xiiplvs.com.

Answer (score 0):

Your style.css has media queries resizing the image. If you have a custom.css you can override this by giving your img id #logo the width and height you desire.

Comment: i want the image to resize depending on the device that the user is on. if you resize the browser you can see that parts of the image get cropped out. I want to avoid this.